# Adding kill to a sudoers group

Tags: sudo, kill, group

How can I give permissions in `sudoers` such that each member of a group is able to kill the process owned by another member of the group?

Scenario: I have two users -- `bill` and `dev-cron` -- who are members of the group `tech`. I'd like `bill` to be able to kill processes started by `dev-cron`.

Answer (score 2):

Where you can put a user name in `sudoers`, you can also put `%` followed by a group name, `+` followed by a netgroup name, or an alias for a list of users (defined with the `User_Alias` keyword.

```
%tech ALL = (%tech) /bin/kill
```

Though considering your use case, I wonder why you don't just use

```
bill ALL = (dev-cron) /bin/kill
```